# How is it possible to solve for singular values of a matrix and how is it different than solving for eigen values?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I am in the process of teaching myself about singular values, SVD and eigenvects.. etc. I am looking at a question asking to find the singular values of a $2\times 3$ matrix, but am unsure what this really means. Can anyone explain the process?

Comment: I am slightly understanding that the sing. values represent the length of the images denoted by Av1/||Av1|| where ||Av1|| is the singular value, can I get a confirmation?

Comment: Your question suggests you're asking for an algorithm. Your comment above suggests something completely different. What do you want exactly?

Comment: I was more or less asking on how to solve for the singular values of a matrix. Is it just the magnitude of each column vector?

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to find the singular values of a matrix $A$?

Comment: yes. Say I have an A matrix, 2x3. Is sing1, sing2 and sing3 the magnitude of their respected col vects?

Comment: By definition, the singular values of a matrix $A$, are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$, in the real case. (In the complex case they are the eigenvalues of $A^*A$). Some authors do not count $0$ has a singular value.

Comment: Ok, that completely makes sense. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: If I answered your question, then I suggest you edit it because it's not clear at all, as it is, that you're just asking for the definition of singular value of a matrix.

Comment: You can also use the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A A^T$ (or $A A^*$ in the complex case).  In some cases, the calculation effort may be smaller - e.g. in your case you have to find eigenvalues of a $2 \times2$ matrix instead of a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

To find the singular values of a given matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ you can:

1) First compute $A^*A$ and note that it is self-adjoint, hence all of its eigenvalues are real.

2) Diagonalize the matrix $A^*A$.

3) Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix computed in step 2.  Now just take the square root of the diagonal entries of $D$ and these are the singular values of the matrix $A$.